# Windows 7 shows blank screen after resuming it from sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sleep

I'am using Windows-7 Home Basic 64 Bit OS. My system has stopped coming out of sleep mode. i.e. if I manually do sleep from `shutdown` menu, or `close the lid`, or `sleep due to power plan`, after re-opening the system, screen doesn't show anything. It remains blank. But everything works the way it should. i.e Hard-Disk, OS keeps running and I can shutdown also by pressing `alt+F4` and `Enter` (in the blank).

I updated display drivers, Graphic drivers, Chipset drivers to the latest version.
What could it be? (corrupt hibernate file?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The c:\hiberfile.sys file is *not* used for sleep mode, only hibernation. So corruption of that file is definitely not the issue here.

This is almost certainly a driver issue. It looks like your graphics card is not correctly handling going from S3 back to S0 (sleep back to fully powered on).

1) Try updating your graphics card driver

2) Try rolling back your graphics card driver to a previous known good version

[image]

3) Failing that driver rollback, try using System Restore to go back to a system state prior to the manifestation of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `powercfg -h off` from an elevated command prompt seems to be working for me, and removed the `hiberfil.sys` file, which I could not otherwise remove, saving precious SSD space.

I'm using an ATI/AMD Radeon HD 7790, and depending on driver version I was getting a wide range of sleep/wake problems. Currently I'm using 13.11 Beta 7, as it seems to have the best PowerCore implementation: saves me 10-20 watts at idle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I finally solved it - the cause of this problem is going to  amaze you! :)

I checked the drivers of both my video card and the built-in graphics card, they both seemed to be updated. then out of no reason at all I decided to go check the power saving settings (sleeping mode, screen poweroff etc..) and the thing I found was that screen poweroff was set to 15 minutes, but computer sleep mode as not set! (i.e was set to 'never') i changed that to 15 minutes, to match the screen poweroff timer, and never had this problem again.

I guess that screen poweroff and computer sleep mode go together - if the PC is'nt sleeping, it does not expect a waking command, therefore will not turn on the screen.

I also tried to set them both to never, and left it a night. As expected, the PC remained as I left it. Its a bit power consuming solution, but is also a good one.

Answer (score 0):

it may be **GRAPHIC DRIVER** problem. Try to install latest version. see the other instructions to fix that - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/black-screen-after-sleep-mode-windows-8/d759b75d-4784-4a82-bf48-a1cb78275db3

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. The screen then turns on and I choose *Cancel* and everything is normal.